# Xslt2.0, How to identify the mix of positive and negative numbers inside strings

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an xml like this (see below). 
Using xslt2.0, I need to find whether any one  contain a mix of positive and negative numbers ?

Weights:  concantenated string of positive/negative numbers..  (separator =  ;).

```
<PriceInfo>
    <price>
        <date>20160124</date>
        <weights>1;2;5;4;</weights>
    </price>
    <price>
        <date>20160125</date>
        <weights>1;2;3;4;</weights>
    </price>
    <price>
        <date>20160126</date>
        <weights>1;-2;3;4;</weights>
    </price>
</PriceInfo>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using `tokenize` you can extract the tokens between `;`, you can then check whether they are integers, if so, convert them, and then you can check whether there are any greater than and any smaller than zero:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="weights">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="integers" select="for $token in tokenize(., ';')[. castable as xs:integer] return xs:integer($token)"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="(some $i in $integers satisfies $i gt 0) and (some $j in $integers satisfies $j lt 0)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks Matin. I took the core concept and modified it to my needs as below in my next comment.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the answer from Martin to suit my needs.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="allWeights" select="string-join(//weights/text(), '')" />                     
     <xsl:variable name="weightTokens" select="for $token in tokenize($allWeights, ';')[. castable as xs:string] return xs:string($token)"/>
     <xsl:variable name="isMixOfPositiveNegativeWeights" select="(some $posToken in $weightTokens satisfies matches($posToken, '[0-9].*')) and (some $negToken in $weightTokens satisfies matches($negToken, '-.*'))"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$isMixOfPositiveNegativeWeights" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```